# AWK command for parameterize

Tags: awk, parameters, gawk

I can run this:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" 'BEGIN{print DATE }1''1; END{print "EOF"NR-1}' Assgmt_B1_v1_16032017.CSV  > NoticesPrinting_v1_farah.csv
```

But after parameterize, I could not run anymore... please help me.

```
 Today_Date=`date +"%d%m%Y"`
 Current_Date=`date +"%d%m%Y"`


awk -v DATE="${Today_Date}" path="${Target_Dir}"'BEGIN{print DATE};END{print "EOF"NR-1}' "${Source_Dir}/${log}" > file= path ""NoticesPrinting_v1".csv"
```

Input:

```
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
10000001|10000002|10000003
```

Output:

```
17032017
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
10000001|10000002|10000003
EOF1
```

Comment: your "non-working" code doesn't set the value of `${Today_Date}`. Assuming you have that in your project, please add that so people can copy/paste your code to reproduce your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Space missing before `'BEGIN`...?

Answer (score 3):

Syntax is wrong in your case

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" 'BEGIN{print DATE }1''1; END{print "EOF"NR-1}' Assgmt_B1_v1_16032017.CSV  > NoticesPrinting_v1_farah.csv
                                                     ^
                                                    Here unnecessary quote
```

Correct like this

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" 'BEGIN{print DATE }1; END{print "EOF"NR-1}' Assgmt_B1_v1_16032017.CSV  > NoticesPrinting_v1_farah.csv
```

**and**

```
awk -v DATE="${Today_Date}" path="${Target_Dir}"'BEGIN{print DATE};END{print "EOF"NR-1}' "${Source_Dir}/${log}" > file= path ""NoticesPrinting_v1".csv"
                            ^                   ^
                        Missing -v             Missing space                                                         ^
                                                                                                                  O/p redirection
```

Correct like below

```
awk -v DATE="${Today_Date}" -v path="${Target_Dir}" '
          BEGIN{print DATE};
          END{print "EOF"NR-1}
 ' "${Source_Dir}/${log}" > "NoticesPrinting_v1.csv"
```

and  The backticks (`` `...` ``) is the legacy syntax required by only the very oldest of non-POSIX-compatible bourne-shells and `$(...)` is POSIX and more preferred, at least `$(...)` stands out visually better.

```
Today_Date=`date +"%d%m%Y"`
```

To

```
Today_Date=$(date +"%d%m%Y")
```

See : [Why is $(...) preferred over (`` `...` ``) (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

**Answer to Comment**

> the output is come out but only header and trailer...othr output
>   doesnot appear

```
$ cat f
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
10000001|10000002|10000003

$ Today_Date=$(date +"%d%m%Y")
$ Target_Dir="something"

$ awk -v DATE="${Today_Date}" -v path="${Target_Dir}" '
          BEGIN{print DATE}1;
          END{print "EOF"NR-1}
 ' f
17032017
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
10000001|10000002|10000003
EOF1
```

Comment: the output is come out but only header and trailer...othr output doesnot appear @AkshayHegde

Comment: @Jiji: change from `BEGIN{print DATE}` to `BEGIN{print DATE}1;` in second command, then you will get everything

Comment: awk -v DATE="${Today_Date}" -v path="${Target_Dir}" -F\,
          'NR==1 {h=$0; next} BEGIN {print DATE}; 
      {file= path "NoticesPrinting_v1_"DATE".csv";
      print (a[file]++?"":DATE ORS h ORS) $0 > file} 
         END{print "EOF"NR-1}' "${Source_Dir}/${log}"  @AkshayHegde cannot run above?